# Used mouse to turn off wifi, how to turn back on with Terminal?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless, terminal

This is a question, but also kind of thinking out loud. I hope I'm not the only one whose curiosity is piqued by this and wants the answer:

**Situation:**

I was using VNC to access my Raspbian Pi (static IP) and accidentally clicked the Wifi icon up top, then clicked Turn off Wifi (or whatever it's actually named). Obviously my VNC lost connection.

So I plugged in a keyboard and tried turning it back on through the terminal locally:
`sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` (didn't work)
`sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (adjustments found online didn't work)
`sudo nano /etc/networks/interfaces` (adjustments found online didn't work here either)
`sudo raspi-config` (re-entering wifi settings here didn't work)

Then I figured (took my brain long enough) that since I turned it off with the mouse, maybe try turning it back on with the mouse. Worked (after a reboot).

**Question:**

What's the difference? And how could I have used terminal to properly turn it back on? I'm under the impression that anything can be accomplished via the terminal. Is that true?

Thanks in advance

*P.S. Side note, if anyone has experience running a wordpress server on a pi or any machine really, I could use some real help on my other question here. All insights are very much appreciated!

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291690/cant-upload-media-to-my-raspberry-pi-wordpress-server*

Comment: Did you try `ifup wlan0` ?

Comment: From my short online research, I read that that command was replaced, presumably by `ifconfig wlan0 up`. I just ran it to see, and it says: `ifup: unknown interface wlan0` (reminder: my setup works now, this is just for educational purposes)

Comment: if you do an ifconfig, what interfaces show?

Comment: At the time, wlan0 didn't show up. Just eth0, lo, and tun0. Then I would try `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` and it would say that it can't do that...something referring to "RF-kill" (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following commands turns on WIFI for me:

```
rfkill unblock 0
```

here 0 refers to the device type id

```
sudo rfkill list all


0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 0):

why can't you try to press the wifi icon and press you internet or maybe just connect with a LAN-cable or did i understand something wrong?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/130428)